# Failed to convert parameter value from string to decimal(when field is empty)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I got a problem which is half done.

Now the problem  is I wrote

Using vb.net and mssql 2014 ent as backend

This is my Query I wrote

```
cmd = New SqlCommand(("insert into FAMPAR(Open_Bal, Curr_Bal, Disc_Perc, Stop_Days, Fix_Days) values(@Open_Bal , @Curr_Bal , @Disc_Perc , @Stop_Days ,@Fix_Days)"), con1)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Open_Bal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtOpeningBal.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Curr_Bal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtCurrBal.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Disc_Perc", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtDisc.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Stop_Days", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtStopDays.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Fix_Days", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtBillOutstdg.Text
ExecuteQuery1()
```

Now everything works fine when I write in every field in vbform but when I left one field empty then it creates exception.

> SystemformatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a string
>   to a decimal...

Now it shows `systemformatException` so is it error in system side or is it error sql side...???

And I have to keep boxes empty sometimes and sometimes filled(no problem when text boxes are filled, query executes successfully), so what can I do with this???

Comment: Why exactly would you expect an empty string to be able to magically become a number?  Stop using strings where numbers are expected.  YOU should be converting those strings to numbers and then YOU can do whatever is appropriate when no number is present, e.g. notify the user that they have failed to enter a valid value or perhaps use zero.  Also, what happens if the user enters "Hello World" in one of those text boxes?

Comment: I had resticted textboxes that they can only enter number and a '.'(dot) @jmcilhinney  Moreover I have made something like if stopdays are 0 then the program will stop the user to make more data of that

Comment: So apparently I cant let the textbox default to 0 if the user din't added any data... Show me alternate way to write a query then friend.. I just taught of writing queries using parameters 3 days before from stackoverflow @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a validation in your code to check if the value is empty or not. You can use the Decimal.TryParse Method See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx). If the value is empty, assign '0' value in the text. From the example in the link:

`If Decimal.TryParse(txtOpeningBal.Text, number) Then
   cmd.Parameters.Add("Open_Bal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = number
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Add("Open_Bal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = DBNull.value
End If`

*Note:* The above was just an example.

Comment: Is there any alternate way, because I can't add 0 to the empty field, it will validate users further.

Comment: Is you column Nullable? If yes, the solution I suggest is to insert a null value.

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm thinking. You can try passing `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: okie, but how should I write like passing the null value in parameters will work???

Comment: thanx, i say you after trying it, it'll work I guess

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to apply Val() function to value before assigning it like bellow

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Open_Bal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtOpeningBal.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Curr_Bal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtCurrBal.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Disc_Perc", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtDisc.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Stop_Days", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtStopDays.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Fix_Days", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtBillOutstdg.Text)
```